# Question about part of Comment.module

Tags: comments

The following is part of the comment.module file (line 950):

```
// Add indentation div or close open divs as needed.
if ($is_threaded) {
  $prefix .= $comment->divs <= 0 ? str_repeat('</div>', abs($comment->divs)) : "\n"     . '<div class="indented">';
}
```

Can someone explain that what is it doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, this is in the [comment_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_view/7) function.

It is equivalent to this, which makes it a little easier to understand:

```
if ($is_threaded) {
  if ($comment->divs <= 0) {
    $prefix .= str_repeat('</div>', abs($comment->divs));
  }
  else {
    $prefix .= "\n" . '<div class="indented">';
  }
}
```

`$is_threaded` is a boolean value for whether or not threading has been enabledfor comments in the settings for this content type.

$comment->divs is set in [comment_prepare_thread()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_prepare_thread/7) and is a count of the indentation divs required to have this comment in the right place in terms of the comment's depth. So this value will either be 1 if a new indentation div needs to be added to make sure the comment is at the correct depth, or a negative number, which is how many indentation divs need to be closed to have the comment at the correct depth.

So if comment threading is enabled, then if `$comment->divs` is less than or equal to zero then close zero or more indentation divs by appending `str_repeat('</div>', abs($comment->divs))` to the markup otherwise, if `$comment->divs` is 1 then open a new indentation div by adding `'<div class="indented">'` to the markup.

For example if you had these comments:

```
Comment 1
-Comment 2
--Comment 3
---Comment 4
--Comment 5
---Comment 6
----Comment 7
-----Comment 8
-----Comment 9
Comment 10
Comment 11
-Comment 12
Comment 13
Comment 14
```

Then for each comment, $comment->divs would be:

- Comment 1: 0
- Comment 2: 1
- Comment 3: 1
- Comment 4: 1
- Comment 5: -1
- Comment 6: 1
- Comment 7: 1
- Comment 8: 1
- Comment 9: 0
- Comment 10: -5
- Comment 11: 0
- Comment 12: 1
- Comment 13: -1
- Comment 14: 0

Comment: Thank you so much. So just let me see if I have understood it. For example if $comment->div is equal to -5, it means that 5 threaded comments were made, so have to add 5 </div>tag to close each of them, so they will be displayed as thread comments. But if $comment->div is equal to 1, it means it is not a threaded comment and is a new comment, so just have to open <div> with class="indented" for it.am I right?

Comment: If $comment->divs is 1, then it means that the comment is a reply to the previous comment and should be indented. If it is -5 it means that the previous comment was 5 levels deeper than the current comment so 5 indentation divs need closing. For example if comments 2 to 6 are all nested replys to comment 1 then you are 5 levels deep of indenting. If comment 7 is then another top level comment then it should not be indented so $comment->divs will be -5 because the previous 5 indenting divs need closing to get back to the top level.

Comment: I added an example if that helps.